# Yii 2 basic template Installation Issue

Tags: yii2

I followed Yii official website guide to install **yii 2 basic template (2.0.43)** several times.
The original site works quite well.
While when I keep on using Gii tool to create a new controller, the Gii tasks finished successfuly.
When I try to open the new page, I got a 404 error.

Finally, I resolved it. The new controller file *CityController.php* as below,

```
<?php
namespace app\Controllers;  // Finally I found there should be a little letter 'c';
```

Could you please tell me why there was a big letter 'C' since I already followed the official tutorial step by step.

thx.

Comment: Commented: yii2-app-basic (2.0.43) used ,and after I corrected the big C to little c. my problem solved.

Comment: Great work solving your own issue! You are [encouraged to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that it can serve as documentation for anyone else that has the same issue in the future. 48 hours  after posting you will be able to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: @tjheslin1thanks for commented above. Acutally I really want to know why the issue occured. That's why I posted as a question. :-)

Comment: Controller class name (including namespace) is something that you provide explicitly in Gii form. So I guess that this uppercase `C` comes from you. If you're on Windows, validation may not complain about this (because your filesystem is not case-sensitive), but autoloading may not work if your FQN does not match directory structure.